# How do you make an instance variable available to the application.html.erb file in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a situation where I want to use an instance variable from a method in all views in a Rails application and I was wondering what is the 'Rails' way to do this.

If I had this situation where I had this code in my `subscriptions_controller.rb`:

```
def index
    @subscriptions = current_user.subscriptions
end
```

What would I do to make this instance variable available to my `application.html.erb`?  I tried doing this but it doesn't work:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def index
    @subscriptions = current_user.subscriptions
  end
end
```

The `@subscriptions` instance variable is nil, and I'm not too sure why.  What is the best way to do this in Rails?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting your instance variable using a `before_filter` in your `ApplicationController`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_filter :set_subscriptions

  def set_subscriptions
    return if current_user.nil?
    @subscriptions ||= current_user.subscriptions
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks for the answer is there another way besides the method that you showed above to make an instance variable available to the application.html.erb view? (I'm just wondering for my own knowledge)

Comment: You can explicitly set it inside your `application.html.erb` but I don't recommend that.